# aws cloudformation template for spot request in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, spot-instances

I need a sample cloud formation template to add spot requests while provisioning the ec2 instance in AWS.I have tried with console to provision spot instances but I couldn't find any exact template for add spot request in ec2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can create a SpotFleet resource, here's an example

```
SpotFleet:
 Type: AWS::EC2::SpotFleet
 Properties:
   SpotFleetRequestConfigData:
     IamFleetRole: !GetAtt [IAMFleetRole, Arn]
     SpotPrice: '1000'
     TargetCapacity:
       Ref: TargetCapacity
     LaunchSpecifications:
     - EbsOptimized: 'false'
       InstanceType:
         Ref: InstanceType
     ImageId:
       Fn::FindInMap:
       - AWSRegionArch2AMI
       - Ref: AWS::Region
       - Fn::FindInMap:
         - AWSInstanceType2Arch
         - Ref: InstanceType
         - Arch
     SubnetId:
       Ref: Subnet1
     WeightedCapacity: '8'
   - EbsOptimized: 'true'
     InstanceType:
       Ref: InstanceType
     ImageId:
       Fn::FindInMap:
       - AWSRegionArch2AMI
       - Ref: AWS::Region
       - Fn::FindInMap:
       - AWSInstanceType2Arch
       - Ref: InstanceType
       - Arch
     Monitoring:
       Enabled: 'true'
       SecurityGroups:
        - GroupId:
            Fn::GetAtt:
            - SG0
            - GroupId
      SubnetId:
         Ref: Subnet0
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Arn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - RootInstanceProfile
        - Arn
      WeightedCapacity: '8'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Spot-fleet resource.

Example :

```
"SpotFleet": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SpotFleet",
  "Properties": {
    "SpotFleetRequestConfigData": {
     "IamFleetRole": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "IAMFleetRole", "Arn"] },
     "SpotPrice": "1000",
     "TargetCapacity": { "Ref": "TargetCapacity" },
     "LaunchSpecifications": [
     {
         "EbsOptimized": "false",
         "InstanceType": { "Ref": "InstanceType" },
         "ImageId": { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
                      { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref": "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] }
                     ]},
          "SubnetId": { "Ref": "Subnet1" },
          "WeightedCapacity": "8"
     },
     {
         "EbsOptimized": "true",
         "InstanceType": { "Ref": "InstanceType" },
         "ImageId": { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
                      { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref": "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] }
                     ]},
          "Monitoring": { "Enabled": "true" },
          "SecurityGroups": [ { "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SG0", "GroupId" ] } } ],
          "SubnetId": { "Ref": "Subnet0" },
          "IamInstanceProfile": { "Arn": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "RootInstanceProfile", "Arn" ] } },
          "WeightedCapacity": "8"
         }
         ]
     }
   }
}
```

More details can be found in this link :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-spotfleet.html

Comment: Thank you ! but in azure we can make spot instance with 3 paramerter like

Comment: "priority": "Spot",
"evictionPolicy": "Deallocate",
"billingProfile": {
    "maxPrice": -1
}https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/spot-template same way in aws we can make it?

Comment: in aws have ec2 fleet option is there may i know the advantage https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ec2fleet-spotoptionsrequest.html

Comment: @aryabraj, I guess those 3 are additional properties which can be added. Complete json sample format is given in same link just below those 3 parameters (big one!!).I guess you need that sample format to create spot instances in azure. Moreover, it all depends on cloud platform which you are using. Respective template for cloud platform will differ from other platform.

Comment: from this request i am getting spot request as fleet, nut i need to create spot instance means spot request type as instance, through console we can enable spot request type while provision a instance, same way have any parameter available in  cloudformation template